# Delphi xe8 wsdl import - no soap header

Tags: web-services, delphi, wsdl, delphi-xe8

After importing a wsdl, no TSOAPHeader classes have been generated, hence no elements  are in the request. The operation element in the wsdl:

```
<wsdl:operation name="searchTdsProviderIndividual">
    <wsoap12:operation soapaction="" style="document">
    <wsdl:input>
        <wsoap12:header message="tns:searchTdsProviderIndividualInMsg" part="productHeader" use="literal">
        <wsoap12:header message="tns:searchTdsProviderIndividualInMsg" part="signatureHeader" use="literal">
        <wsoap12:header message="tns:searchTdsProviderIndividualInMsg" part="timestampHeader" use="literal">
        <wsoap12:header message="tns:searchTdsProviderIndividualInMsg" part="userHeader" use="literal">
        <wsoap12:body parts="request" use="literal">
    </wsoap12:body></wsoap12:header></wsoap12:header></wsoap12:header></wsoap12:header></wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
        <wsoap12:header message="tns:searchTdsProviderIndividualOutMsg" part="productHeader" use="literal">
        <wsoap12:header message="tns:searchTdsProviderIndividualOutMsg" part="signatureHeader" use="literal">
        <wsoap12:body parts="response" use="literal">
    </wsoap12:body></wsoap12:header></wsoap12:header></wsdl:output>
    <wsdl:fault name="standardError">
        <wsoap12:fault name="standardError" use="literal">
    </wsoap12:fault></wsdl:fault>
</wsoap12:operation></wsdl:operation>
```

The soap request that is produced:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0"?-->
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap-env:body>
        <searchtdsproviderindividual xmlns="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/svc/ProviderSearchTdsProviderIndividual/5.1.0">
            <familyname xmlns="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/xsd/providermessages/SearchTdsProviderIndividual/5.1.0">Smith</familyname>
            <dateofbirth xmlns="" xsi:nil="true">
        </dateofbirth></searchtdsproviderindividual>
        <product xmlns="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/xsd/common/CommonCoreElements/3.0">
            <vendor xsi:nil="true">
            <productname>xxx</productname>
            <productversion>1.8</productversion>
            <platform>
        </platform></vendor></product>
        <timestamp xmlns="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/xsd/common/CommonCoreElements/3.0">
            <created xsi:nil="true">
        </created></timestamp>
        <signature xmlns="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/xsd/common/CommonCoreElements/3.0">
            <signature xmlns="" xsi:nil="true">
        </signature>
        <user xmlns="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/xsd/common/CommonCoreElements/3.0">
            <qualifier xmlns="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/xsd/common/QualifiedIdentifier/3.0">http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/id/hi/vendorid/1.0</qualifier>
            <id xmlns="http://ns.electronichealth.net.au/hi/xsd/common/QualifiedIdentifier/3.0">XXX00001</id>
        </user>
    </signature></soap-env:body>
</soap-env:envelope>
```

Comment: Are You sure that header classes aren't there ? Search for : _di_ISOAPHeaders and eventually show generated file. Remember that You must insert headers before call.

Comment: Also some older versions of delphi didn't fully support soap. Wchich version are You using?

Comment: xe8 (edited title). 'soaphead' does not appear in the generated file.